# Formatar data no Angular para Java.util.Date

Tags: angularjs, java-ee, rest, vraptor

Tenho a seguinte data gerada no AngularJS: `2015-09-14T18:38:03.637Z` quando tento dar um POST acontece o seguinte erro no backend:

> Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2015-09-14T18:38:03.637Z"    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.serialization.gson.DateGsonConverter.deserialize(DateGsonConverter.java:59)
>     ... 56 more

No angular faço da seguinte forma: `contato.data = new Date();` o atributo que receberá essa data no `backend` é do tipo `Java.util.Date`. Já tentei dessa forma:

`contato.data = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');`

Porém não funcionou.
Como posso converter essa data?

Método que faz o POST:

```
    @Post
    @Path(value = "/salvar")
    @Consumes(value = "application/json", options = WithoutRoot.class)
    public void salvar(Contato contato) {
        System.out.println("Empresa: " + contato.getNome());
        contatoDAO.salvar(contato);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As datas enviadas para o `backend` do [vraptor](/questions/tagged/vraptor) precisam estar no formato esperado pelo serializador usado na sua aplicação.

Aparentemente, nesse caso, o [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) está sendo utilizado, e o formato esperado por ele é geralmente do tipo `Sep, 14 2015 6:38:03 PM`.

Uma boa biblioteca para se fazer o *parse* da data do *javascript* é a [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). Com essa biblioteca, o *parse* seria algo desse tipo:

```
contato.data = moment((new Date()).getTime()).format('MMM D, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
```

Caso não funcione, pode ser que o formato esperado seja diferente do que eu citei acima. Para obter o formato exato, faça um `GET` para algum *endpoint* da aplicação que retorne um json cujo algum dos atributos do objeto seja gerado a partir de um `Java.util.Date`.